# Why am i unable to read an xpath with selenium in python from a PowerBI webpage

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, powerbi

I'm trying to read the number of confirmed cases of COVID-19 form the webpage of my state here in Brazil, but the page is really had to get the data from it. It is a PowerBI webpage, and the number of cases is on the second page of the presentation. I can read normally anything from the first page, but I can't seem to read anything from the second one (after I click the button to change to the next page, which is in the footnotes of the page). My code is this right now

```
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

class PowerBIBot:
    def __init__(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()
        self.driver.get("https://app.powerbi.com/view?r=eyJrIjoiMDgwOGI4YjItNGFjNC00ZThkLWIyNzctMmNjZTQxMmU1ZjRhIiwidCI6Ijg3ZTRkYTJiLTgyZGYtNDhmNi05MTU3LTY5YzNjYTYwMGRmMiIsImMiOjR9&fbclid=IwAR1U64ZAVQ0IZ9RkiZnO7K7ysbvGtAGHCJWqIbIG8Z7SBfcM8hLSv7B2JSU")
        sleep(8)
        test = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/ui-view/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div/exploration-container/exploration-container-legacy/div/div/exploration-host/div/div/exploration/div/explore-canvas-modern/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/visual-container-repeat/visual-container-modern[3]/transform/div/div[3]/visual-modern/div/div")
        # This works
        print(test)
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/ui-view/div/div[2]/logo-bar/div/div/div/logo-bar-navigation/span/a[3]/i') \
            .click()
        sleep(8)
        try:
            element = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 25).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[1]/ui-view/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div/exploration-container/exploration-container-legacy/div/div/exploration-host/div/div/exploration/div/explore-canvas-modern/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/visual-container-repeat/visual-container-modern[3]/transform/div/div[3]/visual-modern/div/svg/g[1]/text")))
            print(element)
        finally:
            pass

PowerBIBot()
```

In there you have URL of the website I'm trying to read automatically. I know the code is not so good but I'm just trying to get a sense of how selenium works and how I can read these PowerBI pages, which are really hard to read for some reason. I tried waiting for a long time for the page to load, but it never works. Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**: This is the website for easier access: https://app.powerbi.com/view?r=eyJrIjoiMDgwOGI4YjItNGFjNC00ZThkLWIyNzctMmNjZTQxMmU1ZjRhIiwidCI6Ijg3ZTRkYTJiLTgyZGYtNDhmNi05MTU3LTY5YzNjYTYwMGRmMiIsImMiOjR9&fbclid=IwAR1U64ZAVQ0IZ9RkiZnO7K7ysbvGtAGHCJWqIbIG8Z7SBfcM8hLSv7B2JSU

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
#click next page
WebDriverWait(self.driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "i[title='Next Page']"))).click()

try:
    elements = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 25).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@class='card' and @aria-label != '']")))
    for element in elements:
        print(element.get_attribute('aria-label'))
finally:
    pass
```

Comment: So, the part to click on the next page did not work, so I changed it back to the way it was (just finding the element by the x-path and clicking on it), and it worked! Thanks a lot! But now I'm wondering why it worked... Is there any way I can see more explicitly what is happening when selenium is making requestes?

Comment: @Iscod I think just need to learn about `Selenium Locator Strategy`. In this case, you use absolute xpath, it is vulnerable to change, if you want to use xpath, you should use relative xpath.

Comment: @Iscod feel free to hit upvote `^` button if this answer useful :) for future reader

Comment: I did it when you answered it, but I did not have enough reputation at the time... hahaha